# Is it possible to convert `Borrow<T>` to `AsRef<T>` or vice versa?

Tags: rust

I have a variable `tokens: &[AsRef<str>]` and I want to concatenate it into single string:

```rust
// tokens: &[AsRef<str>]
let text = tokens.join("") // Error
let text = tokens.iter().map(|x|x.as_ref()).collect::<Vec<_>>().join("") // Ok, but...
```

The second is awkward and inefficient because it reallocates items to a new `Vec`.

According to [the source code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/library/alloc/src/str.rs#L84-L91), `join` can be applied to `tokens` if its type is `&[Borrow<str>]`:

```rust
// if tokens: &[Borrow<str>]
let text = tokens.join("") // OK

// so I want to convert &[AsRef<str>] to &[Borrow<str>]
let text = convert_to_borrow(tokens).join("")
```

How should I do that? Why is `Join` implemented for types that implement `Borrow` but not `AsRef`?

Comment: I agree that `join()` would make sense for `AsRef<str>` as well. I don't think this was designed with trait objects in mind, though – it's just to support both `&str` and `String` with a single implementation. Your first implementation looks fine to me – the single `Vec` allocation is unlikely to hurt performance in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be slightly slower, but you can `collect` an iterator of `&str`s directly into a `String`.

```
let text: String = tokens.iter().map(|s| s.as_ref()).collect();
```

This is possible because [`String` implements `FromIterator<&'_ str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html#impl-FromIterator%3C%26%27a%20str%3E). This method grows the `String` by repeatedly calling `push_str`, which may mean it has to be reallocated a number of times, but it does not create an intermediate `Vec<&str>`. Depending on the size of the slices and strings being used this may be slower (although in some cases it could also be slightly faster). If the difference would be significant to you, you should benchmark both versions.

There is no way to treat a slice of `T: AsRef<str>` as if it were a slice of `T: Borrow<str>` because not everything that implements `AsRef` implements `Borrow`, so in generic code the compiler can't know what `Borrow` implementation to apply.

Comment: This is basically equivalent to creating a new string and then calling `push_str()` repeatedly, so it has the potential of resulting in many more allocations than allocating the intermediary vector.

Comment: Or, if possible, you can do `let mut s = String::with_capacity(N); s.extend(...);` with a big enough `N` and avoid both the `Vec` and the reallocation.

Comment: Finally, I've changed my function to accept `Borrow` not  `AsRef`. I found that `Borrow` is faster than `AsRef`.

Answer (score 4):

[Trentcl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63247016/493729) gives you a solution to your actual problem by relying only on the `AsRef<str>` implementation. What follows is more of an answer to the more general question in your title.

Certain traits carry with them invariants which implementations must enforce. In particular, if implementations of `Borrow<T>` also implement `Eq`, `Hash`, and `Ord` then the implementations of those traits for `T` must behave identically. This requirement is a way of saying that the borrowed value is *"the same"* as the original value, but just viewed in a different way. For example the `String: Borrow<str>` implementation *must* return the entire string slice; it would be incorrect to return a subslice.

`AsRef` does not have this restriction. An implementation of `AsRef<T>` can implement traits like `Hash` and `Eq` in a completely different way from `T`. If you need to return a reference to just a part of a struct, then `AsRef` can do it, while `Borrow` cannot.

All this means that you cannot derive a valid `Borrow<T>` implementation from an arbitrary `AsRef<T>` implementation: the `AsRef` implementation may not enforce the invariants that `Borrow` requires.

However, the other way around does work. You *can* create an implementation of `AsRef<T>`, given an arbitrary `Borrow<T>`:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;
use std::convert::AsRef;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

pub struct BorrowAsRef<'a, T: ?Sized, U: ?Sized>(&'a T, PhantomData<U>);

impl<'a, T, U> AsRef<U> for BorrowAsRef<'a, T, U>
where
    T: Borrow<U> + ?Sized,
    U: ?Sized,
{
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &U {
        self.0.borrow()
    }
}

pub trait ToAsRef<T: ?Sized, U: ?Sized> {
    fn to_as_ref(&self) -> BorrowAsRef<'_, T, U>;
}

impl<T, U> ToAsRef<T, U> for T
where
    T: ?Sized + Borrow<U>,
    U: ?Sized,
{
    fn to_as_ref(&self) -> BorrowAsRef<'_, T, U> {
        BorrowAsRef(self, PhantomData)
    }
}
```

```
fn borrowed(v: &impl Borrow<str>) {
    needs_as_ref(&v.to_as_ref())
}

fn needs_as_ref(v: &impl AsRef<str>) {
    println!("as_ref: {:?}", v.as_ref())
}
```

---

> Why is `Join` implemented for types that implement `Borrow` but not `AsRef`?

This is a blanket implementation, for *all*  types that implement `Borrow<str>`, which means it can't also be implemented for types that implement `AsRef<str>`. Even with the unstable feature `min_specialization` enabled, it wouldn't work because having an implementation of `AsRef` is not more "specific" than having an implementation of `Borrow`. So they had to pick one or the other.

It could be argued that `AsRef` would have been a better choice because it covers more types. But unfortunately I don't think this can be changed now because it would be a breaking change.